# Disable remotely downloading webpages using curl/wget

Tags: linux, apache, cdn, iptables, cloudflare

I need to disable remotely downloading my web pages using curl/wget.

I want to disable curl -vv http://www.example.com
and I need to get a result like this

**

- Rebuilt URL to: http://www.example.com/    Trying 12.34.56.78... 
  TCP_NODELAY set  Connected to www.example.com (12.34.56.78) port 80
  (#0)  GET / HTTP/1.1  Host: www.example.com  User-Agent: curl/7.53.1 
  Accept: */*    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  Server: AkamaiGHost 
  Content-Length: 0  Location: http://www.example.com/  Date: Mon, 13
  Nov 2017 05:52:50 GMT  Connection: keep-alive   Connection #0 to host
  www.example.com left intact

**

I am using Apache, Using Cloudflare.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `wget` and `curl` with the rules below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pycurl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC,OR]
```

Just add them to `.htaccess`.